# how can i extract address value from json using php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, extract

i have following json how can i get value of each address from this string and store in comma seperated string

```
   Array
    (
   [ResponseCode] => 0
[ResponseMessage] => OK
[ResponseDateTime] => 5/6/2017 11:46:05 AM GMT
[Data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Pincode] => 400067
                [Address] => Charkop 
                [City] => Mumbai
                [State] => MAHARASHTRA
                [Country] => India
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Pincode] => 400067
                [Address] => Kandivali RS 
                [City] => Mumbai
                [State] => MAHARASHTRA
                [Country] => India
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Pincode] => 400067
                [Address] => Kandivali West 
                [City] => Mumbai
                [State] => MAHARASHTRA
                [Country] => India
            )

    )

   )
```

Please help me to extract the Address field from json and store it in comma seperated in string. the output should be like $address = "Charkop,Kandivali RS,Kandivali West ";

Comment: haven't you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json_decode` and loop the data index

```
$new_arr= json_decode($response_json,true);
$address= '';

foreach($new_arr['Data'] as $add){
    $address.= $add['Address'].",";
}

echo $address;
```

or use this one-liner `array_column()` to get the all of the Address column values then bind them together using commas.

```
$address = implode(",",array_column($new_arr["Data"], "Address"));
echo $address;
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a array and foreach the loop to bind the string.

```
$string = '';
foreach($response['Data'] as $data){
  $string .= implode(',',$data['State']);
}
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this simple solution will help you out. Here we are using `array_column` and `implode` to get the desired output.

In the below code we are retrieving indexes of array using `array_column` and joining columns with `,` using `implode`.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/788400)

```
<?php

$string='{"ResponseCode":"0","ResponseMessage":"OK","ResponseDateTime":"5/6/2017 11:46:05 AM GMT","Data": {"0": {"Pincode":"400067","Address":"Charkop ","City":"Mumbai","State":"MAHARASHTRA","Country":"India"},"1": {"Pincode":"400067","Address":"Kandivali RS ","City":"Mumbai","State":"MAHARASHTRA","Country":"India"},"2": {"Pincode":"400067","Address":"Kandivali West ","City":"Mumbai","State":"MAHARASHTRA","Country":"India"}}}';

$array=json_decode($string,true);
echo implode(",",array_column($array["Data"], "Address"));
```